# Navigation error swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I was trying to implement the cancel bar button as you can see from the image, which return to the previous viewController using dismiss, but when I click the button, nothing appears, do you know why?

[image]

Here's my code to implement that:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let isPresentingInAddTaskMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddTaskMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
    else {
        fatalError("The AddTaskVC is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is okay that only use "dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)", don't need check presenting view controller

Comment: There is one thing i don't get. My add button is connected with the VC's navigation, which means the VC is presented by UINavigationController, so why doesn't' the code work?

Comment: else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)

    } -> This is to return when user edit a cell so I can't remove it :((

Comment: Have you debugged it to see which clause it is entering for your if-statement? That would be useful to know.

Comment: Yes, it always enter the else if block for no reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, this is what your view controller hierarchy looks like:

For adding a new task:

> Navigation Controller --(containing)--> "Managing Mode" --(modal)--> Navigation Controller --(containing)--> "Add New Task"

For editing a task:

> Navigation Controller --(containing)--> "Managing Mode" --(push)-->  "Add New Task"

The problem is that neither of your cases will actually work.

#### isPresentingInAddTaskMode

In the first case, we see this:

```
let isPresentingInAddTaskMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

if isPresentingInAddTaskMode {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'd assume this would handle the case involving the modal presentation.

This will never be true, because `presentingViewController` is the "Managing Mode" view controller, not the navigation controller containing it or the navigation controller containing the "Add New Task" view controller.

Another problem with this is that you have to dismiss the navigation controller containing "Add New Task", not "Add New Task" itself. This means that instead of

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you would do

```
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

#### owningNavigationController

In the second case, we see this:

```
else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
    owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

The first line makes sense: you're unwrapping the navigation controller. However, you then call `popViewController(animated: true)` on the navigation controller.

The problem with that is that both the modal and the push segues involve a navigation controller, so this case will work for both.

#### The Solution

You need to form a simpler `cancel` method using the above:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let owningNavigationController = navigationController else {
        fatalError("The AddTaskVC is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }

    if owningNavigationController.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == owningNavigationController {
        // modal
        owningNavigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // push
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

This first unwraps the navigation controller and errors out if there is none, like what you did originally.

You then check, through a more complex way than before, if the modal segue occurred. This checks the navigation controller's `presentingViewController` and if it is itself. If so, it's modal and it dismisses itself. If not, it's a push segue and you pop the current view controller.